PySpark applying multiple transformations takes too long
I have a scenario where there will be multiple json files in S3 bucket, which my Pyspark script will load into dataframe.
Each json will have following structure -
[
    {
        "RECORDS_HEADER": {
            "RECORD_TYPE": "HEADER",
            "DATA": {
                "COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_001": 1,
                "COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_002": 3,
                "COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_003": 6,
                "COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_004": 3,
                "COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_005": 1,
                "COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_006": 1,
                "COUNT_OF_OBJECTS_RECORD_TYPE_007": 0
            }
        },
        "RECORDS_001": {
            "RECORD_TYPE": "001",
            "DATA": {
                "MEMBER_ID": "U3652928373",
                "INDIV_ID": "3003790",
                "MBR_PREF_LANG": "English",
                "MBR_PREF_LARGE_PRINT": "N",
                "BATCH_BEGIN_DATE": "01/01/2023",
                "BATCH_END_DATE": "11/30/2023",
                "BATCH_RUN_DATE": "12/18/2023",
                "BATCH_ID": 1000000078,
                "BATCH_STATUS": "COMPLETE",
                "COLATERAL_TYPE": "EOB"
            }
        },
        "RECORDS_002": {
            "RECORD_TYPE": "002",
            "DATA": [
                {
                    "CLAIM_NUMBER": "232423113200",
                    "RECEIVED_DATE": "08/30/2023",
                    "PROCESSED_DATE": "09/16/2023",
                    "PAID_DATE": "09/15/2023",
                    "CLAIM_DOS_BEGIN_DT": "08/29/2023",
                    "CLAIM_DOS_END_DT": "08/29/2023",
                    "CONTRACT_ID": "H0354",
                    "PBP": "027",
                    "SEGMENT": "000",
                    "GROUP_ID": "",
                    "CLASS_ID": "",
                    "CLASS_PLAN_ID": "",
                    "RENDERING_PROVIDER_NAME": "ESCHLER, DAVID J",
                    "CLAIM_TYP": "H",
                    "PAR_IND": "Y",
                    "CLAIM_QMB_ELIG": "N"
                },
                {
                    "CLAIM_NUMBER": "23P001125500",
                    "RECEIVED_DATE": "05/30/2023",
                    "PROCESSED_DATE": "06/16/2023",
                    "PAID_DATE": "06/15/2023",
                    "CLAIM_DOS_BEGIN_DT": "05/25/2023",
                    "CLAIM_DOS_END_DT": "05/25/2023",
                    "CONTRACT_ID": "H0354",
                    "PBP": "001",
                    "SEGMENT": "000",
                    "GROUP_ID": "",
                    "CLASS_ID": "",
                    "CLASS_PLAN_ID": "",
                    "RENDERING_PROVIDER_NAME": "PRAC HH, MHK HOME G.",
                    "CLAIM_TYP": "H",
                    "PAR_IND": "Y",
                    "CLAIM_QMB_ELIG": "N"
                },
                {
                    "CLAIM_NUMBER": "23E002114300",
                    "RECEIVED_DATE": "01/30/2024",
                    "PROCESSED_DATE": "01/16/2024",
                    "PAID_DATE": "01/15/2024",
                    "CLAIM_DOS_BEGIN_DT": "01/12/2024",
                    "CLAIM_DOS_END_DT": "01/12/2024",
                    "CONTRACT_ID": "H0354",
                    "PBP": "028",
                    "SEGMENT": "000",
                    "GROUP_ID": "",
                    "CLASS_ID": "",
                    "CLASS_PLAN_ID": "",
                    "RENDERING_PROVIDER_NAME": "ZEN, MAX",
                    "CLAIM_TYP": "H",
                    "PAR_IND": "Y",
                    "CLAIM_QMB_ELIG": "N"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RECORDS_003": {
            "RECORD_TYPE": "003",
            "DATA": [
                {
                    "CLAIM_NUMBER": "23E002113200",
                    "CLAIM_LINE_NUMBER": "2",
                    "CLAIMLN_DOS_BEGIN_DT": "08/29/2023",
                    "CLAIMLN_DOS_END_DT": "08/29/2023",
                    "BILLING_CODE": "96401",
                    "BILLING_CODE_DESC": "Complex medication injected",
                    "LINE_NOTES_CODE": "B",
                    "TOTAL_CHARGE": "475.00",
                    "ALLOWED": "0.00",
                    "PAID_AMT": "0.00",
                    "PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY": "0.00",
                    "DEDUCTIBLE": "0.00",
                    "COINSURANCE": "0.00",
                    "COINSURANCE_PCT": "0.00",
                    "COPAY": "0.00",
                    "CLAIM_STATUS_DENIED": "Y",
                    "OVERAGE_AMOUNT": "0.00"
                },
                {
                    "CLAIM_NUMBER": "23E002113200",
                    "CLAIM_LINE_NUMBER": "4",
                    "CLAIMLN_DOS_BEGIN_DT": "08/29/2023",
                    "CLAIMLN_DOS_END_DT": "08/29/2023",
                    "BILLING_CODE": "96401",
                    "BILLING_CODE_DESC": "Complex medication injected",
                    "LINE_NOTES_CODE": "B",
                    "TOTAL_CHARGE": "475.00",
                    "ALLOWED": "0.00",
                    "PAID_AMT": "0.00",
                    "PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY": "0.00",
                    "DEDUCTIBLE": "0.00",
                    "COINSURANCE": "0.00",
                    "COINSURANCE_PCT": "0.00",
                    "COPAY": "0.00",
                    "CLAIM_STATUS_DENIED": "Y",
                    "OVERAGE_AMOUNT": "0.00"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RECORDS_004": {
            "RECORD_TYPE": "004",
            "DATA": [
                {
                    "CLAIM_NUMBER": "123443536",
                    "CLAIM_TOTAL_CHARGE": "1800.00",
                    "CLAIM_ALLOWED": "900.00",
                    "CLAIM_PAID_AMT": "700.00",
                    "CLAIM_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY": "200.00",
                    "CLAIM_COPAY": "200.00",
                    "CLAIM_COINSURANCE": "0.00",
                    "CLAIM_DEDUCTIBLE": "0.00",
                    "CLAIM_OVERAGE_AMOUNT": "0.00"
                },
                {
                    "CLAIM_NUMBER": "123443536",
                    "CLAIM_TOTAL_CHARGE": "1000.00",
                    "CLAIM_ALLOWED": "335.77",
                    "CLAIM_PAID_AMT": "268.62",
                    "CLAIM_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY": "67.15",
                    "CLAIM_COPAY": "0.00",
                    "CLAIM_COINSURANCE": "67.15",
                    "CLAIM_DEDUCTIBLE": "0.00",
                    "CLAIM_OVERAGE_AMOUNT": "0.00"
                },
                {
                    "CLAIM_NUMBER": "123443536",
                    "CLAIM_TOTAL_CHARGE": "1900.00",
                    "CLAIM_ALLOWED": "0.00",
                    "CLAIM_PAID_AMT": "0.00",
                    "CLAIM_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY": "0.00",
                    "CLAIM_COPAY": "0.00",
                    "CLAIM_COINSURANCE": "0.00",
                    "CLAIM_DEDUCTIBLE": "0.00",
                    "CLAIM_OVERAGE_AMOUNT": "0.00"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RECORDS_005": {
            "RECORD_TYPE": "005",
            "DATA": {
                "PROCESSED_PERIOD_AMOUNT_CHARGED": "4700.00",
                "PROCESSED_PERIOD_ALLOWED_AMT": "1235.77",
                "PROCESSED_PERIOD_PAID_AMT": "968.62",
                "PROCESSED_PERIOD_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY": "267.15"
            }
        },
        "RECORDS_006": {
            "RECORD_TYPE": "006",
            "DATA": {
                "YEAR_BEGIN_DT": "01/01/2024",
                "YEAR_END_DT": "12/31/2024",
                "START_DATE": "01/01/2024",
                "END_DATE": "11/30/2024"                
            }
        }
    }
]

When all json files are loaded into single dataframe, then the dataframe looks like below format -
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|         RECORDS_001|         RECORDS_002|         RECORDS_003|         RECORDS_004|         RECORDS_005|         RECORDS_006|      RECORDS_HEADER|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|{{01/01/2023, 11/...|{[{08/29/2023, 08...|{[{0.00, 96401, C...|{[{900.00, 0.00, ...|{{1235.77, 4700.0...|{{B, 11/30/2024, ...|{{1, 3, 6, 3, 1, ...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+

Now I have multiple validations to do on each row under the nested json columns.
So I have created below list of expressions -
["CASE WHEN RECORDS_001.DATA.MEMBER_ID = '' OR RECORDS_001.DATA.MEMBER_ID IS NULL THEN 'MEMBER_ID is missing' ELSE NULL END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_001.DATA.MBR_PREF_LANG = '' OR RECORDS_001.DATA.MBR_PREF_LANG IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'MBR_PREF_LANG is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_001.DATA.MBR_PREF_LARGE_PRINT = '' OR RECORDS_001.DATA.MBR_PREF_LARGE_PRINT IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'MBR_PREF_LARGE_PRINT is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_005.DATA.PROCESSED_PERIOD_AMOUNT_CHARGED = '' OR RECORDS_005.DATA.PROCESSED_PERIOD_AMOUNT_CHARGED IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'PROCESSED_PERIOD_AMOUNT_CHARGED is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_005.DATA.PROCESSED_PERIOD_ALLOWED_AMT = '' OR RECORDS_005.DATA.PROCESSED_PERIOD_ALLOWED_AMT IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'PROCESSED_PERIOD_ALLOWED_AMT is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_005.DATA.PROCESSED_PERIOD_PAID_AMT = '' OR RECORDS_005.DATA.PROCESSED_PERIOD_PAID_AMT IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'PROCESSED_PERIOD_PAID_AMT is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_001.DATA.BATCH_BEGIN_DATE = '' OR RECORDS_001.DATA.BATCH_BEGIN_DATE IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'BATCH_BEGIN_DATE is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_001.DATA.BATCH_END_DATE = '' OR RECORDS_001.DATA.BATCH_END_DATE IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'BATCH_END_DATE is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_006.DATA.PLAN_DEDUCTIBLE = '' OR RECORDS_006.DATA.PLAN_DEDUCTIBLE IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'PLAN_DEDUCTIBLE is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_006.DATA.SERVICE_CTG_IND = '' OR RECORDS_006.DATA.SERVICE_CTG_IND IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'SERVICE_CTG_IND is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_006.DATA.YT_ALLOWED_AMOUNT = '' OR RECORDS_006.DATA.YT_ALLOWED_AMOUNT IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'YT_ALLOWED_AMOUNT is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_006.DATA.YT_AMOUNT_CHARGED = '' OR RECORDS_006.DATA.YT_AMOUNT_CHARGED IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'YT_AMOUNT_CHARGED is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_006.DATA.YT_PAID_AMT = '' OR RECORDS_006.DATA.YT_PAID_AMT IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'YT_PAID_AMT is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_006.DATA.YT_MEMLIABILITY_AMT = '' OR RECORDS_006.DATA.YT_MEMLIABILITY_AMT IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'YT_MEMLIABILITY_AMT is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN RECORDS_005.DATA.PROCESSED_PERIOD_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY = '' OR RECORDS_005.DATA.PROCESSED_PERIOD_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY IS NULL THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'PROCESSED_PERIOD_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN array_contains(transform(RECORDS_003.DATA.TOTAL_CHARGE, x -> trim(x)), '') OR exists(RECORDS_003.DATA.TOTAL_CHARGE, x -> x IS NULL) THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'TOTAL_CHARGE is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN array_contains(transform(RECORDS_003.DATA.PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY, x -> trim(x)), '') OR exists(RECORDS_003.DATA.PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY, x -> x IS NULL) THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN array_contains(transform(RECORDS_004.DATA.CLAIM_TOTAL_CHARGE, x -> trim(x)), '') OR exists(RECORDS_004.DATA.CLAIM_TOTAL_CHARGE, x -> x IS NULL) THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'CLAIM_TOTAL_CHARGE is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN array_contains(transform(RECORDS_004.DATA.CLAIM_ALLOWED, x -> trim(x)), '') OR exists(RECORDS_004.DATA.CLAIM_ALLOWED, x -> x IS NULL) THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'CLAIM_ALLOWED is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN array_contains(transform(RECORDS_004.DATA.CLAIM_PAID_AMT, x -> trim(x)), '') OR exists(RECORDS_004.DATA.CLAIM_PAID_AMT, x -> x IS NULL) THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'CLAIM_PAID_AMT is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN array_contains(transform(RECORDS_004.DATA.CLAIM_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY, x -> trim(x)), '') OR exists(RECORDS_004.DATA.CLAIM_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY, x -> x IS NULL) THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'CLAIM_PATIENT_RESPONSIBILITY is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN array_contains(transform(RECORDS_002.DATA.CLAIM_DOS_BEGIN_DT, x -> trim(x)), '') OR exists(RECORDS_002.DATA.CLAIM_DOS_BEGIN_DT, x -> x IS NULL) THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'CLAIM_DOS_BEGIN_DT is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN array_contains(transform(RECORDS_002.DATA.CLAIM_DOS_END_DT, x -> trim(x)), '') OR exists(RECORDS_002.DATA.CLAIM_DOS_END_DT, x -> x IS NULL) THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'CLAIM_DOS_END_DT is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN array_contains(transform(RECORDS_002.DATA.CLAIM_NUMBER, x -> trim(x)), '') OR exists(RECORDS_002.DATA.CLAIM_NUMBER, x -> x IS NULL) THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'CLAIM_NUMBER is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END",
                     "CASE WHEN array_contains(transform(RECORDS_007.DATA.PREV_PLAN_OOP_COMBINED_AMT, x -> trim(x)), '') OR exists(RECORDS_007.DATA.PREV_PLAN_OOP_COMBINED_AMT, x -> x IS NULL) THEN concat(FAILED_VALIDATIONS, ',', 'PREV_PLAN_OOP_COMBINED_AMT is missing') ELSE FAILED_VALIDATIONS END"
                     ]

And to apply above validations I Have created below method -
def member_records_validations(self, input_df):
        input_validated_df = input_df
        for validations in FIELD_VALIDATIONS:
            input_validated_df = input_validated_df.withColumn('FAILED_VALIDATIONS',
                                                               expr(validations))

        input_validated_df = input_validated_df.withColumn('VALIDATION_STATUS', when(
            col('FAILED_VALIDATIONS').isNull(), 'PASSED').otherwise('FAILED'))

        return input_validated_df

So in the baove method I am creating new column FAILED_VALIDATIONS and keep on adding the field names which are null or empty.
But the above method is running too long even only for 4 input json files.
Can someone tell me how I can optimize this ?
I am open for any further questions if needed.
Thanks !!

After every Nth step (N = 4 or 5 or 6 etc) materialize the dataframe with. df.cache.foreach(lambda x: x) in the for loop. Having long lineage of transformation slows down final evaluation, so causing evalutation inbetween helps.

Do not use withColumn or withColumnRenamed for such transformations, add all your columns as part of a single select (interim caching etc. is neither needed nor performant).
The query plan will look like it's optimised out but it won't be. Scala based approach, evidence for it.
Additionally, as a warning, building large expression trees like this can cause slowness in building an action (or even with generated code size).  This is one of the reasons for the approaches taken with the various Quality engines.
